# Generar numero id consecutivo con reinicio anual en PHP

Tags: php, autonumeric

Tengo el siguiente código,

```html
<?php
session_start();
/* Inicia validacion del lado del servidor */
if (empty($_POST['sheets'])) {
    $errors[] = "Hojas vacío";
} else if (empty($_POST['title'])) {
    $errors[] = "Asunto vacío";
} else if (
        !empty($_POST['sheets']) &&
        !empty($_POST['title'])
) {

    include "../config/config.php"; //Contiene funcion que conecta a la base de datos        

    $title = $_POST["title"];
    $description = $_POST["description"];
    $sender_id = $_POST["sender_id"];
    $kind_id = $_POST["kind_id"];
    $user_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
    $project_id = $_POST["project_id"];
    $category_id = $_POST["category_id"];
    $priority_id = $_POST["priority_id"];
    $status_id = $_POST["status_id"];
    $attach_id = $_POST["attach_id"];
    $hojas = $_POST["sheets"];
    $created_at = "NOW()";
//                $asigned_id = $_SESSION["asigned_id"];          
//                $publico = $_POST["publico"];
    // $user_id=$_SESSION['user_id'];

    $sql = "insert into document (title,description,sender_id,kind_id,user_id,project_id,category_id,priority_id,status_id,attach_id,sheets,created_at) value (\"$title\",\"$description\",\"$sender_id\",$kind_id,$user_id,\"$project_id\",\"$category_id\",$priority_id,$status_id,$attach_id,$hojas,$created_at)";

    $query_new_insert = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if ($query_new_insert) {
        $messages[] = "Tu documento ha sido ingresado satisfactoriamente.";
    } else {
        $errors [] = "Lo siento algo ha salido mal intenta nuevamente." . mysqli_error($con);
    }
} else {
    $errors [] = "Error desconocido.";
}

if (isset($errors)) {
    ?>
  <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <strong>Error!</strong>
    <?php
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
            echo $error;
        }
        ?>
  </div>
  <?php
}
if (isset($messages)) {
    ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
      <strong>¡Bien hecho!</strong>
      <?php
        foreach ($messages as $message) {
            echo $message;
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

El campo Id de la tabla lo tengo como incremental, pero además necesito que este ID se guarde con el año, pero que cada año reinicie el Id y cambie el año

2017-00280 que quede así actualmente

y el otro año inicie así

2018-00001

Comment: guardando los datos en una tabla? hay muchas formas de hacer esto :(. es muy importante que mires [ask] y [tour]

Comment: Hola Rak. Tu pregunta se basa en opiniones por pedir recomendaciones e igualmente es muy amplia. Has de explicar mejor lo que tratas de hacer y sobre todo mostrar lo que has intentado y por que no te funcionó. Mira [ask] para mejorar tu pregunta. Un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para crear un código de esa forma necesitas hacer una query previa y obtener la cantidad de registros del año actual. Luego incrementas y colocas el formato que sea necesario:

```
<?php 
    // consulta que cuenta los registros del año actual
    $result = query_result("select count(*) as cont from document where year(created_at)=year(now())");
    $cont = $result->cont + 1; //incrementas
    $num = sprintf("%'.05d", $cont); // formato con 5 digitos
    $codigo = date("Y")."-".$num; // concatenas con el año actual
    echo $codigo;
?>
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, vieras que me sirve para el primer registro que guarda, con el segundo me da este error: Error! Lo siento algo ha salido mal intenta nuevamente.Duplicate entry '2017-00001' for key 'PRIMARY' , me parece que no me hace el incremento.

Comment: Verifica el contenido de las variables. Primero verifica que la consulta efectivamente cuente los registros y asegurate de recibir ese valor en una variable. Luego es cuestión de incrementar + 1 a ese valor. Esa es la lógica.

Comment: Si ya revise incluso la consulta aparte y me cuenta los registros pero en el insert me dice que esta duplicada

Comment: Cree un if con el código que me diste y quedo solucionado

Answer (score 0):

Trabajar este tipo de cosas con archivos de texto es mala idea, pero solo es para ilustrar los pasos a seguir.

Suponiendo que estás trabajando con un archivo de texto, guardas año, un caracter de separación y el contador, ejemplo: 2017|123.

```
// Obtienes el año actual
$year = date('Y');
// Obtienes datos del archivo
list($cYear, $cCount) = explode('|', file_get_contents('counter.txt'));
if($year == $cYear) {
    // Si el año almacenado es el actual, entonces tomas el valor e incrementas
    $cCount ++;
} else {
    // De lo contrario, hay que actualizar año y reiniciar contador
    $cYear = $year;
    $cCount = 1;
}
// Actualizas los datos
file_put_contents('counter.txt', "$cYear|$cCount");
// Continúas con la ejecución de tu script, sabiendo que:
// Año = $cYear y Contador = $cCount
```

Es mejor si lo trabajas con base de datos para evitar problemas de lectura/escritura de archivo, principalmente cuando hay varios usuarios accediendo al mismo tiempo.

Comment: Hola Triby. Gracias por aportar una respuesta pero ten en cuenta para futuras ocasiones el esperar a publicarla cuando la pregunta sea de baja calidad. Has de esperar a que se mejore porque si no, con tu respuesta, se está indirectamente promoviendo que se hagan preguntas pobres. Un saludo

Comment: Gracias, lo tendré en cuenta para la próxima.